# The update query don't work php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote an update query in php for mysql but the query doesn't work.

```
$baglanti11 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx","php","");

$okulmdmay = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "okulmdma"); // when i print $okulmdmay i give b
$menuno = 14;

$veridegis13 = $baglanti11 -> prepare("update menu set menuadi = ? where no = ?") or die("0");
$veridegis13 -> bindParam(1, $okulmdmay) or die("1");
$veridegis13 -> bindParam(2, $menuno) or die("2");
$veridegis13 -> execute() or die("3");
```

[image: Image of the database]

I don't see the problems in the table. The problem is the name of the menu is `a` and I would like to change this to `b`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: why you need so many `die()` here?

Comment: `$veridegis13->commit();` maybe you don't have autocommit

Comment: @ArtOsi to see if there's any error

Comment: Might be more helpful to use PDO's [error functions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) instead of echoing out 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Yeah, but errors like "1", "2", "3" doesn't look very informative

Comment: define "doesn't work". Does it fail on one of your die() statements? Or does the query run but not update anything? Please show the POST variables you supplied. Like the others said, it would be better if you logged the actual error somewhere when it dies.

Comment: You can call `commit()` on `PDO` object not `PDOStatement` object. Why would you use `commit()` here anyway? You don't have any transactions to commit as I see